# How to get relative path in Integration Testing in c#

Tags: c#

### Problem

I am trying to test my importing service in which I have to provide file which is save in the same solution but different folder and also there are bunch of project in it too and this folder is out of the projects. I want this path to be absolute path how can I do this?

I am doing in this way

```
string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"E:\Development\Project\Misc Artifacts\ImportFileSamples\city.txt");
```

Comment: what is not working? what kind of application is it?

Comment: this my test project in my solution and my files are saved out of that project in folder

Comment: I asked you 2 questions and you did not answer any of them...

Comment: I is working with absolute path but I need to relative path of the file. second it is web application and i am testing in (integration testing)

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath("~") gives you root path relative to your application. You can specify the rest of the path and use it to fetch your file.

Like Server.MapPath("/ImportFileSamples")

You already have the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to find the relative path.

```
var relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(
@"C:\X\API\APITest.Tests\IntegrationTest\ServiceLayerTests"
@"C:\X\API\API.Test.Tests\Images\)";
```